# How to create a dynamic database connection in spring mvc application at runtime?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web-applications, spring-jdbc

So I have a spring mvc application. One of the requirements is that a user can execute some queries against a specific database of their choice. So a form is provided to user to input all needed database details to obtain connection. Usually in most cases we will have some preconfigure database connections (xml/jndi) but in this case the connection needs to happen at runtime after user submits details. I can have some database manager that returns a connection based off the users submitted details but wanted to see if anyone knows of another more effecient way to handle something like this.

Not looking for code specifics but rather design approach/idea to go about this...Or if there is other framework that can help with connection management in these situations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [AbstractRoutingDataSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html) that will be an intermediary that selects a specific datasource at runtime, based on some criteria

you can read more at [Dynamic Source Routing](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/)

or a newer and more complete example at [AbstractRoutingDataSource example](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/12/28/spring-3-2-5-abstractroutingdatasource-example/)

Comment: thnx. I will take a look. At first quick glance, looks like in this approach there are multiple defined data sources, that are being switched in and out. Hopefully there is a way to include totally new sources (not yet defined).